# Как отобразить код элемента в виде форматированного текста

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как с помощью JS, или JQuery можно отобразить в теге `<pre>` тег и содержимое тега `<script id="js">` в виде форматированного текста? Желательно без костылей вида `replace(/</g,'&lt;')`

```
<pre></pre>
<script id="js"> var x=y; </script>
```

примерно так

```
$("pre").html($("#js").clone());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что бы отобразить содержимое, надо отобразить содержимое.

```js
output.textContent = test.outerHTML;
```

```html
Output:
<pre id="output"></pre>
<script id="test">
  var x = 0;
  x++;
  console.log(123); // To be sure that this script runs once
</script>
```

Comment: Скрипт всегда "runs once", надо в нём html-кода бояться. Впрочем, у этом ответе всё верно.

Answer (score 3):

**UPD. после комментария:**

*Пример на codepen, если так удобнее: [ссылка](https://codepen.io/meine89/pen/MZBrRw)*

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('script').outerHTML;
var pre = document.getElementById('pre');
pre.textContent = elem;
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
<script id="script">
  function HelloWorld() {
    alert('Hello world!');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Я там немного отредактировал вопрос, вот примерно так но с тегом script и его атрибутами. При это очень желательно не оборачивая его в другой тег

Comment: @Nsk, Обновил решение.

Comment: Первый вариант - вообще жуть - там же теги могут быть. Нафига использовать `innerHTML`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, Вы правы, потерялся просто.

Comment: Мог бы просто `pre.innerHTML` заменить на `pre.textContent` в нём.